# Duvida sobre player de musica para site

Tags: php, ajax, youtube

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer um player de musicas para site, com AJAX, PHP ou HTML5, usando uma playlist do youtube. Tem como fazer ele reproduzir em modo aleatorio essa playlist para não ficar repetindo sempre a mesma ordem todas as vezes?

Comment: Leia esse link, e vá navegando na api do youtube, tem coisas que podem te ajudar nisso: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list?hl=pt-br

Answer (score 0):

Segundo o [Youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/171780?hl=pt-BR):

**Incorporar uma playlist**

1. Em um computador, faça login em sua conta do YouTube.
2. No lado esquerdo da página, clique em Playlists.
3. Clique no título da playlist que você deseja incorporar.
4. Clique em Compartilhar .
5. Clique em Incorporar.
6. Copie o código HTML da caixa que aparecerá.
7. Cole o código no HTML de seu blog ou website.

Apenas HTML.

**Edição:** conforme o comentário do [Leonardo Patrício](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8181/leonardo-patricio), caso queira, o [Youtube disponibiliza sua API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/) para aplicações diversas.

Comment: ta msi tem como eu deixar ele em reprodução aleatoria?para que toda vez que a pessoa entre no site não comece com a mesma musica

Comment: Você vai utilizar a opção em HTML ou a API? Se for com a API, você pode tentar algo como sugerido na resposta http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866979/youtube-api-playlist-shuffle-not-working
Neste outro link, tem vários exemplos de implementações em Java/Python/PHP https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channelSections/list com o Shuffle também

Comment: ta mais não estou entendo como isso vi funcionar. Eu tenho que fazer um `SCRIPT` com os codigos no player do site?

Comment: leonardopessoa usei o um codigo que tem nos exemplos que vc postou mas ele não inicializa a play list, ele carrega o video mas não da play

Comment: Qual navegador você utilizou? Chrome/Firefox/Safari?